# Auto-Update Userform Label when combo boxes change values

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform with a labelcaption that is invisible until a combo-box is filled out.

```
Private Sub ComboBox18_Change()
Dim Val As String

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("User Dashboard").Range("L18").Value = Me.ComboBox18.Value
Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
Label13.Visible = True
End Sub
```

This label value is affected by other combo-boxes and should update if those combo boxes change.

Is there a way I can update the label13.caption when any/a certain combo box (rankcombo) is updated?

I tried :

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_AfterUpdate()
Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
Label13.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

This too:

```
Private Sub Rankcombo_Change()
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
    Label13.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

Anything is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Click event

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
    Label13.Visible = True 
End Sub
```

EDIT: Extract the caption update to a different procedure and then call it from the multiple comboboxes click event

Like this:

ComboBox1 click event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Click()
    LabelCaptionUpdate
End Sub
```

---

ComboBox18 click event:

```
Private Sub ComboBox18_Click()
    LabelCaptionUpdate
End Sub
```

---

Update label caption procedure:

```
Sub LabelCaptionUpdate()
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
    Label13.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This did work, but after combo box 18 is applied, this feature won't update label13.

Comment: See my edit refering to repeat the process with multiple combo boxes

Comment: ricardo diaz, thank you so much! I had to add calculate as the workbook is set to manual, but adding lablecaption as its own action worked. thank you!

Comment: Sub LabelCaptionUpdate()
    Calculate
    Label13.Caption = Sheets("User Dashboard").Range("K24").Text
    Label13.Visible = True
End Sub